# multiple drop down list validation when select item using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have two select elements. If "2 Wheeler" is selected from the first `<select>`, I'd like the next list to be automatically validated and "2 wheels" to be shown.

How can I make it possible to do it?

This is my code ;

```
<form method="post" id="target">
 <select id ="selected1" name="expenseType" class="dynamic_select" >
     <option value="0">-select-vehicle-type-</option>
     <option value="1">2 Wheeler</option>
     <option value="2">4 Wheeler</option>    
 </select> 
  <select id ="selected2" name="expenseType" class="dynamic_select" >
     <option value="0">-select-Parts-</option>
     <option value="1">2 wheels and Parts</option>
     <option value="2">4 wheels and Parts</option>
 </select> 
 <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Validation is done using jQuery.

Comment: what do you mean validate the next list?  do you mean filter the next select list to what's available or do you mean you want to flag certain selections from the second select as invalid if they choose a wrong option?

Comment: @JoshMeiburg ofcourse.. and sorry about my langage..

Comment: Are you using the [jQuery Validation plugin by Bassisstance](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)?

Comment: @Sparky Why r u down vote this question..

Comment: I didn't say anything about down-voting.  I simply asked you which plugin you're using.

Comment: @Sparky am sorry for that .. i don'd know about plugins .. in my question i say one thing i don'nt how to use jquery..but the question will edited.. that is why you r down voting this question.. and really sorry that's my problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do this by disabling options that aren't valid in the second select based on the selection in the first select.  check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4WYLj/)

use data tags to enrich your html

```
<form method="post" id="target">
    <select id="selected1" name="expenseType" class="dynamic_select">
        <option value="0">-select-vehicle-type-</option>
        <option value="1" data-type="data-2wheel">2 Wheeler</option>
        <option value="2" data-type="data-4wheel">4 Wheeler</option>
    </select>
    <select id="selected2" name="expenseType" class="dynamic_select">
        <option value="0">-select-Parts-</option>
        <option value="1" data-2wheel>2 wheels and Parts</option>
        <option value="2" data-4wheel>4 wheels and Parts</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

then hook up the jquery

```
$('#selected1').on('change', function () {
    var option = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var secondSelect = $('#selected2');

    secondSelect.find('option').prop('disabled', false);
    secondSelect.find('option:not([' + option.data('type') + '])').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty simple as you're using jQuery already;

```
  $("#selected1").change(function(){
      $("#selected2").val($(this).val());
});
```

Click here for JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qjvzw/

Comment: how to this connect with database..

Comment: connect with database means ? you want to bind second dropdown value from database when dropdown1 is change?

Comment: http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html  Read this blog

Comment: ok that's really helps..

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

HTML:

```
<select id ="selected1" name="expenseType" class="dynamic_select" >
     <option value="0">-select-vehicle-type-</option>
     <option value="1">2 Wheeler</option>
     <option value="2">4 Wheeler</option>    
</select> 
<select id ="selected2" name="expenseType" class="dynamic_select" >
</select> 
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selected2').append('<option value="0">-select-Parts-</option>');
});


$('#selected1').change(function(){
    $('#selected2 option').each(function(index, option) {
        $(option).remove();
    });
     $('#selected2')
         .append('<option value="0">-select-Parts-</option>');
    if($('#selected1').val() == "1")
    {
        $('#selected2')
         .append('<option value="1">2 wheels and body</option>');
    }
    else if($('#selected1').val() == "2")
    {
        $('#selected2')
        .append('<option value="2">4 wheels and body</option>');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vge68/)